# How does this implementation of array intersection work?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, stl, intersection

This code finds the intersection of two unsorted array.

```
void intersection(int arr1[],int m,int arr2[],int n)    //where m=size of arr1 and n=size of arr2
{
  map<int,int>mapp;

  for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
     mapp[arr1[i]]++;    //3

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    if(mapp[arr2[i]] >0)    //4
    {
      mapp[arr2[i]]--;     //5
      cout<<arr2[i] <<endl;
    } 
  }
}
```

What actually it is trying to do in line 3, 4, and 5?

Comment: All three of those are using values stored in their respective arrays as keys to a map associating values to counters. And note, this code is a potential path for *undefined behavior* if `m < n` holds true, due to the use of `arr1[i]` at `//4`.

Comment: It doesn't matter what these lines do. The previous comment lightly touched on it, but based on the description of the parameters, and the stated purpose of this function, it's quite obvious that the shown logic is fundamentally flawed, and will fail to produce correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**3**: this can be written a little bit more clearly like this:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    int value1 = arr1[i];
    int currentCount = mapp[value1];
    mapp[value1] = currentCount + 1;
}
```

This makes it easy to interpret. Store all values of `arr1` as keys in `mapp` and increment its value by 1 each time the same value is met. Here we'll assume that any value should always start at 0.

**4**: again, we'll rewrite this so it becomes more clear:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int value2 = arr2[i];
    int currentCount = mapp[value2];
    if (currentCount > 0) {
        mapp[value2] = currentCount - 1;
        cout << value2 << endl;
    }
}
```

In the `if`-statement we try to find a value already existing in `mapp`.
Again assuming the values are by default 0: we will skip any value that wasn't found in the first array.
If it is found, its count will be greater than 0 and we continue inside the `if`.

**5**: the previous example contains the rewrite

So we only enter the `if` when the key is present in `arr1` as well as `arr2`.
If that is the case, we simply deduct the counter by 1 so it only shows up once for each time the value is in both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an array arr1[] = {2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3}.

After using this sort of code,

```
map<int,int>mapp;

  for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
  mapp[arr1[i]]++; //3
```

The mapp will be stored like follow,

mapp[2] = 2

mapp[3] = 3

mapp[4] = 1

That means an unique element repeats how many times in arr1.

Now come back to the main portion. Intersection of two array means the elements that have in both arrays.

```
mapp[arr2[i]] >0 //4
```

This line is ensuring that arr2[i] element have in arr1 at least one time. If mapp[arr2[i]] == 0 that means it's not in the arr1(confused?). Why I am saying arr1. Because we iterated the mapp through arr1. Remember what you commented as "3".

```
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
  mapp[arr1[i]]++;
```

For your 5...

Let's see an example.

For each element in arr2, if that is also in arr1, just cross it. Actually it's gonna be the element of the array after intersection.

arr1 = {<strike>2</strike> , <strike>2</strike> , 2 , 2 , <strike>3</strike> , 5}

arr2 = {<strike>2</strike> , <strike>2</strike> , <strike>3</strike> , 4}

After intersection {2, 2, 3}

The crossing thing is actually,

```
mapp[arr2[i]]--; //5
```

It is too difficult to demonstrate in this way. But I tried my best :)

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is using a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to associate to each value stored in the array a count of the number of occurrences found.  The map is ordered.

The first iteration just count the values that exist in the first array.  So if the first array contains 3,2,3 and 5, the statement `//3` will update the map to get the following association:

```
key   counter value
2   ->   1
3   ->   2
5   ->   1
```

The second iteration goes through the second array. Numbers that were not already in the first array are ignored (because there map value would be 0 at best, that's the purpose of `//4` ).

For the matching number, it decreases the number of unmatched value in the map and display the value.

So if the second array contains 1, 3, 5, 3, 3,  the iterations would look like follows

```
1 -> mapp[1] is 0 so this number is ignored (indeed it was not in the first array)
3 -> mapp[3] is 2 so the count is decreased to 1 and 3 is printed.  
5 -> MAPP[5] is 1 so the count is decreased to 0 and 5 is printed, 
3 -> mapp[3] is 1 (see above), so the cound is decreased to 0 and 3 is printed
3 -> mapp[3] is 0 (see above), so either 3 was never found in the first array, or all the count occurences were already matched.  So nothing is done.
```

The algorithm will print the results in the order of occurence of the numbers in the second array.  It unfortunately populates `mapp` with a 0-value for all the elements in `arr2` that are not already in `arr1`, since the sher fact of accessing a key in the map with `[]` will create a 0 value for it. Checking presence of a value in the map with [`.find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) would be a better approach.